# How to get leftmost boundary in a SVG?

Tags: svg

I have an SVG image of a stickman like this: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/539177224/stickman_grey.svg

How can I get the relative boundary position of his left arm? Is there an easy way to generalise finding the boundaries(left, right, top, bottom) for all svgs?

Comment: call getBBox on an element to get its bounding box.

Comment: That doesn't work if you set the preserveAspectRatio value to xMidYMid

Comment: Depends what co-ordinate system you want the answer in. getBoundingClientRect may be what you want if you want that factored in.